# SELECT only rows that aren't repeated

Tags: oracle

So I have a table like this. This is a standard Order header - Order Detail table:

```
       order id   order_line
      ----------- ----------- 
         100          1       
         100          2
         100          3
         101          1
         102          1
         103          1
         103          2
         104          1
         105          1
```

Now, how can I make a SELECT that will only pick the orders that only have one line?
In this case I don't want orders 100 and 103.

Thanks!
Tiago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counting lines using "group by order_id" is a good solution, however counting is not needed, simpler Max function works fine:

```
select order_id from orders 
    group by order_id 
        having max(order_line)=1;
```

In case order_line has consecutive values further "optimization" is possible:

```
select order_id from orders
    where order_line <= 2 
    group by order_id 
        having max(order_line)=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by the `order_id` and take only those having 1 record per group

```
select order_id 
from orders
group by order_id
having count(*) = 1
```

If you need the complete record then do

```
select t1.* 
from orders t1
join
(
    select order_id 
    from orders
    group by order_id
    having count(*) = 1
) t2 on t1.order_id = t2.order_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following query too :

```
select order_id , order_line 
from Order_Detail 
group by order_id ,order_line 
having count(order_id)<2;
```